# I want to choose my own Server and own database in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I am very newly in google app engine.. There are three Questoins on google app engine and in google app engine i want to choose JAVA language.

1. Does google app engine provide private cloude ?
2. I want to deploy my application with my own server( E.x.glassfish or JBoss) on google app engine ?
3. I want to use my own database instead of cloud SQL in google app engine?

Is it possible or not?

Answer (score 2):

With Google Cloud Appengine - no, it's impossible.

With Google Cloud Instances or Google Cloud Containers - all of this is possible.

Appengine is just one piece of Google Cloud, designed for very specific job, with infrastructure managed by Google. You can only write some code (with lot of restrictions too) that runs inside it. You can read some details about code restritions there: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/#Java_The_sandbox

What you're looking for is Google Cloud Instances, that are more standard virtual machines, where you can run anything you want. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/

There is still tools for Load Balancing, Health Check, Centralized Logging for Cloud Instances, and other stuff similar to features provided by Appengine.